# Android - как ещё можно ускорить вставку в базу SQLite?

Tags: android, java, sqlite

Здравствуйте! По совету из прошлого вопроса я не стал записывать нулевые ячейки в базу, теперь объём записываемых данных уменьшился с `25 165 824` до `6 881 280`. Вопрос: можно ли ещё как-нибудь ускорить сохранение (сейчас оно занимает 140 секунд, хотелось бы сократить это время хотя бы до минуты) этих данных в базу?

Вот мой код сохранения:

---

```
    void save()
    {
        final SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path, null);
        String sql_w_table = 
            "CREATE TABLE w_data (" +
            "a LONG," +
            "b LONG," +
            "type LONG" +
            ");";
        database.execSQL(sql_w_table);

        String query = "INSERT INTO w_data VALUES (?,?,?);";
        SQLiteStatement st = database.compileStatement(query);

        database.beginTransaction();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 32767; i++)
        {
            for (int n=0; n <= 255; n++)
            {
                int b = map[i][n];

                if (b != 0)
                {
                    st.bindLong(1, i);
                    st.bindLong(2, n);
                    st.bindLong(3, b);
                    st.executeInsert();
                    st.clearBindings();
                }
            }
        }

        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();
        database.close();           
    }
```

Comment: Что за переменная block1? Может быть это b?

Comment: Да, это b. Исправил.

Comment: посмотрите вот эту статью, весьма полезно, думаю   
http://habrahabr.ru/post/190876/

Comment: Весьма впечатляющая статья.

И интересные выводы напрашиваются...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю самый наивный способ - не сохранять "поячеечно", а "построчно". Попробую на коленке переписать (!!).

```
void save()
{
    final SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path, null);
    String sql_w_table = 
        "CREATE TABLE w_data (" +
        "a LONG," +
        "type TEXT" +
        ");";
    database.execSQL(sql_w_table);

    String query = "INSERT INTO w_data VALUES (?,?);";
    SQLiteStatement st = database.compileStatement(query);

    database.beginTransaction();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 32767; i++)
    {
        String s = '';
        for (int n=0; n <= 255; n++)
        {
            s += map[i][n] + " ";
        }
        st.bindLong(1, i);
        st.bindLong(2, s);
        st.executeInsert();
        st.clearBindings();
    }

    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
    database.close();           
}
```

суть - в базу сохраняем сразу по строке. Когда нужно будет распаковывать, то используем обычный метод split у строки.

Можно пойти дальше и использовать blob и сохранять строку в один подход. Андроидовская обвязка для blob умеет сохранять массив byte. Класс `java.nio.IntBuffer` и `java.nio.ByteBuffer` позволяют завернуть массив int в массив byte. Вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461225/shrinking-android-bitmaps-without-saving-them-as-a-jpeg-file-to-avoid-out-of-mem) как сохраняют картинку в базу.

Но я верю, что сохранение в файл будет как минимум не медленнее (если только не сохранять поэлементно).

Comment: Я немного модифицировал ваш код (http://pastebin.com/19t2puLY), но время сохранения только возросло до 201 секунды.

Comment: Вы плохо модифицировали. По факту, ничего не поменялось относительно Вашего первоначального варианта. И ухудшили. Я предлагаю уменьшить кол-во запросов к базе.

Ещё раз. В обеих ваших вариантах выполняется 8388608 insert'ов. У меня же 32768.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, а теперь попробуйте записать эти структуры просто в локальный файл (конечно, с буферизацией).

Уверен, время сократится до десятка секунд.

Comment: @avp, мне нужна структуризация, поэтому сохранение в локальный файл не поможет.

Comment: а что понимается под "структуризацией"? То что это массив? Или там ещё другие данные сохраняются? И как там с производительностью моего оригинально кода?

Comment: @KoVadim, будут сохраняться ещё другие данные, но уже в совсем маленьких количествах.

С вашим кодом сейчас разбираюсь, нужно ещё прикрутить проверку на if (b != 0)

Comment: попробуйте без нее. Просто для теста. В данном случае выкидывать нули может оказаться немного накладнее.

Answer (score 1):

Одного не понимаю, зачем здесь нужны транзакции в локальной БД куда юзер/аппа имеет монопольный доступ? Ну я бы еще понял, если автор где-то при ошибке вставки откатывал бы транзакции и проч. - но этого ведь нет. Раз так, то напрашивается рецепт:

для ускорения вставок я бы рекомендовал установить наинизший возможный уровень изоляции транзакций:

```
PRAGMA read_uncommitted = 1;
```

И убрал бы словеса `beginTransaction/endTransaction` и проч. ненужную в данном контексте муть

Еще бы поигрался с местом хранения временных файлов:

```
PRAGMA temp_store = 0 | DEFAULT | 1 | FILE | 2 | MEMORY;
```

Comment: учитывая, что у андроида приложение может просто быть прибитым системой, совет очень полезный:) (получить сломанную базу:)) )

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду, bulk insert вам поможет.

Comment: Вроде я и использую Bulk Insert. Не могли бы вы привести в пример немного кода, пожалуйста?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить другой вариант синхронизации:

> PRAGMA synchronous = 0 | OFF | 1 | NORMAL | 2 | FULL;

Но тут надо понимать что если вырубание питания, или ещё какой непредвиденный косяк у Вас может "умереть" база. Хотя PRAGMA synchronous = 0 скорость увеличится раз в 10сять.

И попробуйте ещё закидывать не по одному инсерту а по "пачке".

Comment: вот чего люди не придумывают, что бы только не использовать транзакции и делать себе приключения.

Comment: @KoVadim, так судя по коду, дядя использует транзакции. Если поставить NORMAL то уже будет достаточно производительности (FULL по умолчанию). OFF это конечно если совсем для больших объёмов (> 1000 000) - т.к. может много чего плохого случится. А у вопрошающего 6 лямов записей. Чтобы быстро их загнать традиционные методы не подойдут. Не для sqlite.

Comment: посмотрите на мой вариант ответа, где я предлагаю сильно сократить кол-во вставок. Это сильно лучше. Вот только @SuperCreeper почему то фантазирует и не использует его.

Comment: @KoVadim - с архитектурной точки зрения это как раз костыли и есть. Если требуется просто хранилище инфы - то проще всего запихать в файл. Но если будут требоваться анализ этих данных - то Ваш вариант умирает сразу. Хотя это здраво - ускорение за счёт уменьшения количества вставок.

Comment: подозреваю, что автору анализ не нужен. Сохранять в файл он не хочет (то есть уже подписался на костыль).

Comment: Извиняюсь за задержку с ответом, пришлось отойти.

@KoVadim, я прикрутил ваш код. Сохранение идёт за 56 секунд. Великолепно!

Comment: @SuperCreeper, добавтье ещё `PRAGMA synchronous = NORMAL` - сохранять будет за 10 секунд.

Comment: @KoVadim, а это нормально, то что размер базы сократился в 4 раза? Было 20МБ, а стало 5.

Comment: вполне. сделайте простой подсчет. раньше на одну запись нужно было минимум 12 байт (3 поля по 4 байта). на 256 записей это 3072 байта. В новом способе это 4 + 256 * (1+длина инта). Так как объем базы стал в 4 раза меньше, то  выходит, что в среднем у вас двух-трехзначные числа. Может они там все не больше 256?